# How to dynamically increase size of a relative layout based on length of text?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I've a relative view such as this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/linkCardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@layout/login_gradient_bg"
        >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/card_bg">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/linkTitle0001"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/faviconView0001"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="-2dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:text="@string/link_title_001"
            android:textColor="#717171"
            android:textSize="17sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/linkDesc0001"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/faviconView0001"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="@string/link_desc_001"
            android:textColor="#acacac"
            android:textSize="13sp"   />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/faviconView0001"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="6dp"
            android:paddingBottom="7dp"
            android:src="@drawable/favicon_example" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/labelSource0001"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linkDesc0001"
            android:background="@drawable/card_label" />






    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

I wanted to increase the size of the relativeLayout, with the length of text that is filled in linkTitle0001 TextView. How do I achieve that?

Comment: You have its height set to wrap content, and the height of the text view set to wrap content.  So if you put in a bigger string it should automatically increase to fit the text.  Or did you mean something else?

Comment: Yes, I meant that. But its not happening at all.

Comment: What is happening?  A screenshot would be helpful.

Comment: Your code looks correct. Can you just try to set orientation for your framelayout and see..

Comment: @GabeSechan Triyng to get a screen shot, though phone isn't rooted. What's happening is text of linkTitle0001 is overriding on top of labelSource0001

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Try this:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/linkCardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@layout/login_gradient_bg"
        >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/card_bg">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/faviconView0001"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="6dp"
            android:paddingBottom="7dp"
            android:src="@drawable/favicon_example" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/linkTitle0001"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/faviconView0001"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="-2dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:text="@string/link_title_001"
            android:textColor="#717171"
            android:textSize="17sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/linkDesc0001"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/faviconView0001"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="@string/link_desc_001"
            android:textColor="#acacac"
            android:textSize="13sp"   />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/labelSource0001"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linkDesc0001"
            android:background="@drawable/card_label" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>

For Textview linkTitle0001, try to put below something or align baseline with someone as per your need.
```

Comment: linkTitle0001 still overlaps on linkDesc0001

Comment: Thats what I mentioned at the end of my post. You have placed linkTitle0001 rightof faviconView0001. But you have not mentioned its vertical position. If you just want it right of faviconView0001, then also add android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/faviconView0001" for linkTitle0001

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't have a rule to stop that.  source0001 is below desc0001, which is below favIcon0001.  Title is right of favicon, but that doesn't mean the things below it can't overlap it.  Basically, the layout_below doesn't stop it from going further right than that item.  You either need to force all those others to align_right with the favicon (so they can't go to the right of favivon at all), or need to put in rules on all of those items to layout to the left of the title.